# Can not delete Metadata entry in Spatial DB

Tags: oracle, spatial-index, spatial-query

```
I am trying to  a spatial data table in my db using :
```

CREATE TABLE building (buildid VARCHAR(15) PRIMARY KEY, buildname VARCHAR(50),numpoint NUMBER,points SDO_GEOMETRY);

CREATE INDEX building_spatial_idx ON building(points) INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX;

INSERT INTO USER_SDO_GEOM_METADATA(TABLE_NAME,COLUMN_NAME,DIMINFO,SRID)
VALUES (
'building',
'points',
SDO_DIM_ARRAY(    --820*580 grid
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', 0, 820, 1),
    SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', 0, 580, 1)
    ),
NULL --SRID
);

When I executed it for the first time it did not give any errors but afterwords it is giving error

```
insert into user_sdo_geom_metadata values
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (MDSYS.UNIQUE_LAYERS) violated
ORA-06512: at "MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_TRIG_INS1", line 27
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'MDSYS.SDO_GEOM_TRIG_INS1'

Is it happening because am trying to give meta-data for same table again.
```

Or is there any other reason. How can i delete all the index,metadata,table at a single go and remove this error.

Answer (score 0):

A new Schema creation solved the problem,